# Passing a char array but not including the null terminating character

Tags: c, string, char

I have a function that takes in a char array and searches a table for that particular character and it's corresponding value. I am getting the char to search for from user input using fgets, and when I pass the buffer to the lookUp function, it is including the null terminating character which is causing issue as the lookUp is looking for the character + null terminator. My question is, is there a way to 'strip' a char array of it's null terminator or is there maybe a different way to deal with this? Thanks.

```
//lookUp function
//This function was provided for us, we cannot change the arguments passed in.
Symbol* lookUp(char variable[]){
    for (int i=0; i < MAX; i++){
        if (strcmp(symbols[i].varName, variable)==0){
            Symbol* ptr = &symbols[i];
            return ptr;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
} 



//main
int main(){
   char buffer[20];
   Symbol *symbol; 
   printf("Enter variable to lookup\n");
   while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)!= NULL){
      printf("buffer is : %s\n", buffer);
      int i = strlen(buffer);
      printf("length of buffer is %d\n", i);
      symbol = lookUp(buffer);
      printf("Passed the lookup\n");
      if (symbol == NULL){
          printf("Symbol is null\n");
       }
   }
}
```

Output, symbol should NOT be null here.

```
Enter variable to lookup
a
buffer is : a
length of buffer is: 2 //this should only be 1
Passed the lookup
Symbol is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgets() retains the newline if one is there. You want to remove it. One way to do this is:

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)!= NULL){
    char *p = strchr(buffer, '\n'); // new code
    if(p) *p = 0; // new code     
    printf("buffer is : '%s'\n", buffer);
    int i = strlen(buffer);
    printf("length of buffer is %d\n", i);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not about the terminating `NUL` character. If you had read the manual of `strlen()`, you would have learnt that it doesn't include the terminating zero byte when counting the length. It is the **newline character** that `fgets()` appends to the end of the string. And you can strip that by replacing it with a NUL byte:

```
char *p = strchr(buffer, '\n');
if (p != NULL) {
    *p = 0;
}
```